# Can I use the same Java Libraries and Java Code on Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a java programm which uses following libraries:

- commons-codec 1.9
- commons-loggin 1.2
- fluent-hc-4.5.2
- httpclient-4.5.2
- httpclient-cache-4.5.2
- httpclient-win-4.5.2
- httpcore-4.4.4
- httpmime-4.5.2
- jna-4.1.0
- jna-plattform-4.1.0

I have to create a android program which does exactly the same than what the java program does.
So my question is, if it is possible to import the same libraries than in java?

I think this libraries are duplicated. Why?

- fluent-hc-4.5.2
- httpclient-4.5.2
- httpclient-cache-4.5.2
- httpclient-win-4.5.2
- httpcore-4.4.4
- httpmime-4.5.2

Are these used already be default?

I tried following (I don't know where I found this..):

```
    useLibrary: 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Which libraries does this include?

The java code is very easy:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.add("Puls", (new Date()).getTime(), 23.87);
    .... (following)

    DataUploadClient.upload("https://xxx.de/DataUploadServlet",
            "(for you unimportant String)",
            "user", "password", ds.toString());
```

The program should upload datas to the server and save it into a database.

I hope you understand what I mean. What should I change in Android compared to java? Only the libraries? Or should I also change the code?

It's not my server and it's not my code. My task it to get the whole thing working on android.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes you can use it absolutely,given you decompose the solution and use asynctasks to not overburden the main thread

Comment: JNA almost certainly not; that's a wrapper around JNI, isn't it?

Comment: Just know that desktop/server applications aren't exactly meant to be ported to mobile. Http legacy is deprecated, yes, but I think it's http client & core. Maybe mime as well

Answer (score 0):

Android runtime is trimed down version of java , not all (complete) java framework is supported by android.

The JRE that runs on desktop that is oracle jre(java runtime) or open jre .that works using jvm(java virtual machine).

General Java programming , Java code is compiled to bytecode that runs on JVM, while on android java code compiled to bytecode is translated to dex code that runs on dvm(dalvik virtual machine) , dvm is runtime on android.

Android does not support Java enterprise code , java swing gui toolkit , etc.

From android lolipop v5, dvm (dalvik virtual machine) is completly replaced by art thats android runtime